# Load Globalize cultures with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, jquery-globalization

I'm using [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) with Node.js. They have a `package.json` file so I can simply use it as a module and `require` it. However, it doesn't load all cultures by default. I was wondering what the proper way to load a culture would be? I could go and do something like

```
require('./node_modules/globalize/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.es-US.js')
```

and load the file directly, but that doesn't seem too elegant. Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to support all cultures, with a single require:

```
require("./node_modules/globalize/lib/cultures/globalize.cultures.js");
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Globalize NPM package](https://npmjs.org/package/globalize) if you're not doing that already.

It does not seem that there is a proper way to load the cultures included, however. I think the intended usage is to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to package the cultures you need along with the Globalize code itself.

Comment: I see. Could you perhaps provide some details on how to add and package cultures with Grunt, and then I will accept your answer?

Comment: I don't use either Grunt or Globalize, so I can't help you there.